# Вопрос по jQuery (js)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

есть такой вопрос:

[image: необходима реализация на jQuery вот такого выпадания доп информации]

необходимо выпадания доп информации на jQuery , сделал это в тупую для каждого свой класс и отдельное событие на каждую кнопку, можно ли это сделать циклом или другим способом и как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно например для каждой кнопки и блока присвоить уникальный идентификатор (атрибут id), и при этом для всех кнопок присвоить один класс. Чтобы можно было работать с одным событием, при этом различать нажатия например по id родительского елемента и открывать соответственный блок

Вот пример

```js
$( ".change" ).click(function(e) {
 var id_click = e.target.id;
 var parent = $('#' + id_click).parent(".block");
 parent.css('display', 'none');
 console.log();
});
```

```css
.block {
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.block a {
  cursor: pointer;
  float:right;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="block">Block 1 <a class="change" id="1">Click</a></div>
    <div class="block">Block 2 <a class="change" id="2">Click</a></div>
    <div class="block">Block 3 <a class="change" id="3">Click</a></div>
    <div class="block">Block 4 <a class="change" id="4">Click</a></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: А как потом по id именно тому блоку изменить видим/невидим можно пример пожалуйста?

Comment: @MaximMalyi Добавил пример кода в ответ.. по сути он ловит клик по классу change, определяет уникальный id елемента, ищет его родителя и скрывает блок